# Strict vs. Non-strict Evaluation

Tags: programming-languages

I'm having a hard time findindg advantages/disadvantages of Eager Evaluation in comparison to non-strict evaluation and lazy eval.

I'd like to know your thoughts about that, what comparison criteria should be used as well as the advantages/disadvantages.

An additional question is why in Wikipedia 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eager_evaluation

it says: **"or it may delay the evaluation of expressions that have a more immediate need."**

I don't get that part... how'd eager evaluation delay evaluation of expressions that have "more immediate need"? don't understand what that's supposed to mean... any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full sentence is:

> A disadvantage of eager evaluation is that it forces the evaluation of
>   expressions that may not be necessary at run time, or it may delay the
>   evaluation of expressions that have a more immediate need.

Take the following (slightly made up) example:

```
List<Boolean> x = empty list;

// some times later, in some other part of the program
x.add(false);
// even later, in yet anopther part of the program
x.add(is_prime(sum(prime_factors(12345678999997773511111111111873452098612576436))));

// back in main processing
if (all(x)) {
    ....
} else {
   ....
}
```

Where `all` is something like:

```
 boolean all(List<Boolean> it) {
     for (b : list) if not b then return false;
     return true;
 }
```

Here, the result  of is_prime(...) is not strictly needed to compute `all(x)`, hence its computation delays the *more immediate* computation. More immediate because the value `all(x)` is needed to decide how to continue, while - in this case - the value `is_prime(...)` is not needed at all at this time. It may be used later in the `else`branch, though.

Comment: Ingo, thanks for the example. How is it that all doesn't need is_prime to be computed? wouldn't it need the result of the is_prime(...) expression in order to check if every element is a prime in the list?

Comment: @JimGoodall No, the x list is just a list of some booleans (think of it as a list of some propositions to check). **One** of the propositions would be that the sum of the prime factors of that big number is itself prime (I told you I made this up - think of it as just some long running computation). But because the first proposition was false, there is no real need to compute all the other propositions to decide which branch of the if to take - were it not for strict evaluation.

Comment: thanks so much for the clarification! I think it's making sense now...! I don't know if you read the main part of my question? But I'm also interested in having a clear idea about what criteria to use and evaluate advantages/disadvantages of Strict/Non-strict.  I suppose one criteria may be resource usage: memory and processor. But what about language design principles? Does strict vs non strict affect readability, writeability, orthogonality? I'm having a hard time finding a clear explanation in books (have 5 programming language books with me, and the only who explains a bit is Watt)

Comment: Well, @JimGoodall, I did read the main part of your question. But, being myself an author of a language with non-strict evaluation, I do not want to give you (and the community) a biased opinion in an answer. Yet in a comment I might say that I think that the main advantage of non-strictness is with readbility, writeability, orthogonality.

Comment: thanks, I read your bio and saw you are the author of a language (that's why I value your answer a lot, thanks). Hope to find some complete unbiased analysis on this subject somewhere. Because in wikipedia I only found that list of advantages/disadvantages many not fully clear to me. I would love a good comparison with some examples rather than that small list that someone wrote in wikipedia. Thanks a lot for all